# How to fit a curve to a dataset of curves using initial data-points?

Tags: python, machine-learning, plot, graph, data-science

I am trying to fit a curve to these curves for a new data points.
Basically this plot is a representation of the sale speed of a food product for different days.

On the X axis there is time left for production ( in minutes) and on y axis there is cumulative food demand we get for different days [different coloured lines].

What i am trying to find out is given the initial sales velocity for a particular day, how can i predict the nature of the curve?

I want some sort of model which understands the patterns of the curves. and predict the nature of curve given the initial sales velocity.

So basically when the models sees a new data, just from looking at initial data-points of sales velocity at the start of the day, we can predict the nature of the curve. So that we know how much to produce beforehand.

So with more data coming we can predict in a better manner how much would be the final demand at the end of the day. I want to predict at every 10 minututes how is the curve going to look like?

Is there any model or process  to do this?

The plot looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe this falls under the category of Time series analysis. Given a set of points varying with time, you want to forecast the future. You have various time series forecasting models like [ARIMA](https://machinelearningmastery.com/arima-for-time-series-forecasting-with-python/), [SARIMA](https://machinelearningmastery.com/sarima-for-time-series-forecasting-in-python/), etc.

Another method is [Fourier Transform](https://medium.com/@balajiciet/nuts-and-bolts-of-fourier-transform-for-time-series-forecasting-python-c5dc08d0840), which quite accurately models your dataset (but prone to over fit).

One change you might have to do is to combine the data for different days into one single time series data before applying the above methods.